# How to get the index of multiple mininum values in a column?

Tags: python, list, indexing, knn, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to get the k minimun values of each column on a dataframe. however I am unable to get the indices.
I have a dataframe that contains the distances between data called ddist. I want to select the k minimum elements in each column and make a list of the no. of row each element is in so I can use it for KNN later.

These are the lines where I tried to get the indices, however i get a list with the indexes and the values and cannot access the indices alone.

```
list_min = []
for column in ddist:
    idx = ddist.nsmallest(k,column)
    idx=idx[0]
    list_min.append(idx)
list_min
```

the output looks like this

```
[43     0.0
 188    0.0
 202    0.0
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 21    0.04
 26    0.04
 94    0.04
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 27     0.39
 52     0.39
 164    0.39
 Name: 0, dtype: float64,
 33     0.01
 131    0.01
 210    0.01
...
```

but I only want to get the integers that look appear like a column on each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `pd.Series.index`:

```
list_min = []
for column in ddist:
    idx = ddist.nsmallest(k,column)
    idx=idx[0]
    list_min.append(idx.index.tolist())
list_min
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, however I am still unable to access the integers only as the output looks like this :


[Int64Index([43, 188, 202], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([21, 26, 94], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([27, 52, 164], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([33, 131, 210], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([59, 82, 88], dtype='int64'),
 Int64Index([2, 13, 24], dtype='int64'),
...

Comment: @ReginaBriseño Edited my answer should work now, please accept and upvote if it works